# Gradle configuration to use maven local repository

Tags: gradle

I have Maven and Gradle both installed in my system.

By default maven stores the dependency jars in the USER_HOME/.m2/repository and Gradle stores in folder  USER_HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2 respectively.

For the same project, I am end up with 2 copies of jars in my system ultimately.

Is there any configuration to set up in the gradle  at global level so that it uses existing maven repository instead of its own.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
mavenLocal()
```

If location of repository must be in other place you can use

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url '/path/to/your/repository'
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note there is a small difference between mavenLocal() and maven {}.

https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2034
"“This is fixed, but only for mavenLocal(). For all other repositories it is still considered an error for the artifact to be missing when the pom is present (unless packaging == 'pom')”". So maven{} fails if jar is missing in local repo, but mavenLocal does not.

Comment: I think mavenLocal() is used in build.gradle specific to projects. Is there any configuration that we can set in GRADLE_HOME to use the same for config for all projects?

Comment: You can add GRADLE_HOME/init.gradle . In this file you can add configurations for all projects. Look at [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:configuring_projects_from_an_init_script)