# Make Gradle use Maven local repository for downloading artifacts

Tags: java, gradle, repository

I know I can configure Gradle to use local Maven repository

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Can I configure Gradle to download into Local (maven) repository? (So that Maven would also be able to use those jars)

ref [Gradle configuration to use maven local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733297/gradle-configuration-to-use-maven-local-repository)

Answer (score 3):

A solution was given in the gradle forums:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/need-a-gradle-task-to-copy-all-dependencies-to-a-local-maven-repo/13397/2

using this gradle plugin: https://github.com/ysb33r/ivypot-gradle-plugin
you can call a new tasg

```
gradle syncRemoteRepositories
```

which will download all dependencies to a local Ivy repository (which is the same library Maven uses). The folder you point to with

```
syncRemoteRepositories {
   repoRoot '/path/to/repo'
}
```

will contain the dependencies. I would suggest first trying out with a different local path than your M2_HOME, because I saw some warning about the Ivy repository structure having changed between Maven versions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

And

```
gradle install
```

More info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sec:maven_tasks)

Comment: That does not answer the question. He wants to download dependencies into Mavenlocal, not install his own packages to maven local.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks @tkruse "download into Local (maven) repository"

Comment: @PaulVerest, you commented on a different answer, and if you think one answer is right, you can accept it using the accept button.