# How to make Gradle downloads artifacts into .m2 repository

Tags: gradle

Similar to [Make Gradle use Maven local repository for downloading artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804511/make-gradle-use-maven-local-repository-for-downloading-artifacts)
BUT not for newbie I think (like me, sad face).

It's easy to make Gradle use `.m2` repo first, calling `mavenLocal()`, and download into `.gradle\caches` if not exists.

But it will be NICE if Gradle downloads not-exist-artifacts into `.m2` repo instead of `.gradle\caches`.

---

The answer of the question at the top recommended [ivypot-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/ysb33r/ivypot-gradle-plugin) and I used it... epic fail!

If this plugin works, a **newbie-friendly** example code could really helpful!

---

My 'sad' code

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.ysb33r.ivypot' version '0.8'
}

group 'g'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

syncRemoteRepositories {
    repoRoot 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\.m2\\repository'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'
        }
    }

    configurations 'compile', 'testCompile'

    includeBuildScriptDependencies = false
}

repositories {
    ivy {
        url 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\.m2\\repository'
        layout 'gradle'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'com.facebook.presto:presto-jdbc:0.209'
}
```

Comment: Happily, my 'sad' code works after I deleted fail-caused artifacts from .m2. This is becase maven won't download javadoc and resources jar by default but that plugin will download javadoc and resources, so I think I solved my question. BUT is there more nice way to solve this question?

Comment: Have another problem: maven directory pattern is `com/facebook/presto`, but ivy pattern is `com.facebook.presto`. So it can't use mavenLocal()